# Data Binding not refresh when "clear" ObservableCollection of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Windows which contains two Listboxes and one button.
Those two List Box Data Bind to List of Class "ObjectList" and include ObservableCollection in it.
The First ListBox (we will call it "ObjectLists") contain text box in it.
The Second  ListBox (we will call it "ObjectListsSelected") contain Listbox in it.
I use those top Listboxes to get dynamic UI.

The Button executea a command which use to split the text in the first listbox (follow \r\n chars), add them to the second list box and clear the Text Box in first listbox.

I'm having a problem with Data Binding for "ObjectLists".
The Clean option doen't reflect in the UI although the property get this update.

When Debugging this scenario i found out that the Clear action doesn't go to the set of the property.
of course i Used Property Change, but nothing work.

**Main Windows**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListToTextConverter x:Key="converter1"></local:ListToTextConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="ObjPanel">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Object" Height="30"/>
    <ListBox Name="ObjectLists" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding OB1,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Name="ObjectList" Text="{Binding content,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource converter1}}"  Margin="0,0,30,0" Height="225" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Name="AddButton" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">Add</Button>
    <Label Content="ObjectSelect" Height="30" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <!--<ListBox Name="ObjectListSelectedBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjSelected}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="200" Height="225" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>-->
    <ListBox Name="ObjectListsSelected" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding OB2,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox Name="ObjectListSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding content,Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="0,0,30,0" Height="225" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**class ObjectList**

```
class ObjectList
{
    public string header { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _content;

    public ObservableCollection<string> content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
        }
    }

    public ObjectList()
    {
        content=new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

}
```

**Main View Model**

class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; set; }

```
    public List<ObjectList> OB2 { get; set; }

    private List<ObjectList> ob1;

    public List<ObjectList> OB1
    {
        get { return ob1; }
        set {
            ob1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ob1));
            }
    }



    public MainVM()
    {
        this.AddCommand = new RelayCommand(Add);
        OB1 = new List<ObjectList>()
        {
            new ObjectList()
        };
        OB2 = new List<ObjectList>()
        {
            new ObjectList()
        };

    }

    public void Add()
    {
        foreach (var s in OB1[0].content)
        {
            OB2[0].content.Add(s);
        }

        OB1[0].content.Clear();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OB1));

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}
```

**Covertors**

```
public class ListToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type TEST = value.GetType();
        foreach (string s in (ObservableCollection<string>)value) sb.AppendLine(s);
        string str = sb.ToString();
        return str;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] lines = Regex.Split((string)value, "\r\n");
        ObservableCollection<string> OC = new ObservableCollection<string>(lines);
        return (OC);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ListBox with `ItemsSource="{Binding content}"` (where I have removed the pointlesss `Mode=TwoWay` setting) should update when `content.Clear()` is called. However, clearing has no effect for the TextBox with `Text="{Binding content, ...}`. The Text property is not a collection, hence TextBox does not register for INotifyCollectionChanged events. Besides that, any settable property that is used in Bindings should fire a property change notification, also `ObservableCollection<string> content` should do that.

Comment: So how can i clean the text in the textbox? do you have any idea for workaround?

Comment: By implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for the content property, and assigning a new value.

Comment: I Tried to do it in the view model without any success. Should I do it inside the ObjectList Class?

Comment: Sure, the PropertyChanged event has to be fired from the setter of the property that has changed.

Comment: I did it and it didn't work for content.Clear(). However when is Set the Content to null and Update the converter according it finally worked.
Thanks.